# loading clampex .abf files for analysis in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, neuroscience

I am new to matlab, and am looking to analyse gap-free recordings of neurons in the form of .abf files generated in Clampex.
I understand that clampex does not natively support .abf files? How is it possible to import these files for analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following submissions on MATLAB Central File Exchange?

[abfload](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6190-abfload)

[abf2load](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22114-abf2load)

Comment: I have tried but get told not enough arguments when trying to run the files.

Comment: Type `help abfload` to see how to run the files. I haven't tried them myself, but from the look of it you would probably start out by running `abfload('C:\example\myabffile.abf')`, and then there are some optional parameters that you can add in as well.